# Android Widget onClick

Tags: android, widget, onclick

I want to be able to click on a widget and launch a dialog box. I have read the official documentation as some of the unofficial ones. I initially wanted to launch a new activity but even this fails. I get the following in Logcat but I cant really see anything.

```
11-14 21:28:47.929: INFO/ActivityManager(116): Starting: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.app/.Execute bnds=[179,89][300,160] } from pid -1
```

I guess the above means that the intent was passed... But the activity was actually not started. Should the activity to be started be a normal one?

The code used is:

```
public class ExampleAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
        // to the button
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget_provider_layout);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);

        // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm observing  it too. I'm seeing this too -when I try to launch an activity with a notification I've put from one of my application.
I guess it has something to do with the process id being shown as -1
Generally whenever some other activity is launched via an intent, the process id is not as -1, but some different number as assigned by OS..

Comment: My problem has been solved.. The pid being -1 had nothing to do with it.. My actual problem was that I had a typo in my code.. instead of typing as "XYZActivity", I had written "XYZACtivity" (Notice the capital C) and since it was specified as a String, there were no errors thrown by Android.. Maybe there is something similar in your case as well ?

Comment: So, what was the -1 about? Do you mean the activity you wanted to start was misspelled? I dont see any misspellings. How the activity to be launched on widget click treats the intend? Or is this irrelevant?

Comment: For first question -No idea.. I think it is alloted to Notification Bar's process..as it always prints -1 for anything launched via Notification bar.
Second -Yes I had misspelled the name. I had given the name using setClassName() method, and since it was String, there were no Compile-time errors. And regarding the remaining questions related to the widget part, I'm sorry but I do not have any idea on those.. :( Maybe some knowledgeable person might be able to help you with that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause of the problem would be that you haven't declared `ExampleActivity` in your Manifest.

<UPDATE>

You could also try using a unique number for argument 2 of your `PendingIntent` creation and also put a sensible flag in argument 4:

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
```

Comment: i tried that as well. Nothing changed. Is there is any possibility that the activity that is trying to be executed is not coded as intended? I mean is there is something special that i need to include in the new activity to be launched?

Comment: Well, you need to handle the `Intent` that's being added to the `PendingIntent`. You have properly defined `ExampleActivity` in your Manifest, haven't you?